# can i re-use canning jars with botulism

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation

I have a question about botulism when canning pickles. I realize that most canning recipes use 1:1 vinigar to water ratio for canning pickles. I accidently used 1:4 vinigar to water ratio for canning pickles. Now i am wondering if I will get botulism and if so can i re-use the jars or do i have to throw the jars out? if i can re use the jars then what is the best way to clean and steralize them?

Answer (score 1):

Botulism is a spore.  If you suspect botulism you SHOULD NOT open the jar.  If you do, you'll need to wipe down everything with a bleach solution. I don't think the risk is worth saving a jar.  Per the CDC,  wrap the jar tightly in plastic, and throw it away carefully in a way that animals or humans that might be digging through the garbage do not open it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if is is tainted.

Commercially canned goods are required to undergo a "botulinum cook" in a pressure cooker at 121 °C (250 °F) for 3 minutes.

The toxin is killed at a lower temperature.   85 °C (185 °F) for longer than 5 minutes.  But to reuse the can you should kill the organism.  In my opinion.

I agree with the link to just throw it it out if you suspect botulism.